# how to merge git non-master to master branch?

Tags: git, github

Below is the local repo structure :

```
developement      master

    A               A
    B<--------------B
    C           (pushed to
    D           remote/master)   
    E            
    F
    G
    H
```

(pushed to
remote/developement)

I want to make it like below on local as well as master.

```
 developement         master
    
        A               A
        B               B
        C-------------->C
        D-------------->D
        E-------------->E
        F-------------->F
        G-------------->G
        H-------------->H
```

want to discard development branch after merging it to master branch at local repo.

Thank you!

Comment: There are such wonderful things called books, and one of them is about Git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Thanks for comment .
I read something related to this called git rebase.
but worried bcoz I cant try things on this repo .I tried seperately but faced issue after merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have two remote branches, with the solution below I
imagine you having changes on one local branch "non-master" and you want these changes on master.
If this answer does not meet your needs, please leave a comment here and I will be able to edit my solution to fit your needs.

**Note, during merging, you may run into merge conflicts, pick the new changes from the new local branch**

**step 1**
Make sure all changes on your non master branch are committed locally before you checkout to the master.
You can do that by running this command

```
git add .
git commit -m "saved changes on the local branch to be merged into master"
```

Now checkout the master branch so that you can introduce new changes

```
git checkout master
git merge non-master
git add .
git commit -m "merged non-master into master"
git push
```

If you want to delete the local branch

```
git branch -d non-master
```

If you want to delete the remote branch

```
git push origin --delete name-of-remote-branch
```

Incase you have a second remote branch for example development,
checkout on the local version of development,
rebase development on master and push the changes to remote development.

**Those steps would like like this below**

```
git checkout development
git rebase master
```

If you have merge conflicts and you don't remember what piece of code needs to stay or go, abort the rebase and instead do a merge

```
git rebase --abort 
git merge master
```

If one of the two has worked for you, push the changes to your remote origin
now all should be well good.
Solution did not work?, get back to me I will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
After checking out to devlopement branch on local ,I did `git rebase master`
It saying `Current branch devlopement is up to date.`

Comment: Thanks ,I did it by using `git rebase devlopement master` .
Now showing 
`On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'remoterepo/master' by 8 commits.`
seems all commits are appended to master .

I know how to push to remote but not sure about branching at remote repos.
after pushing this chaneges to remoterepo/master branch ,Will it rebase the devlopement branch on github also ? as like local repo rebased.

Comment: if your local master is ahead of remote master, git add . git commit -m "add your message here" and git  push should make both local master and remote master sync. remember running the commands on you local master. 
Still facing problems? let me know whats not working or where you are confused. I will be glad to help.

Comment: about the update of remote branches, when you are done pushing the latest changes to remote master. and you want the remote development branch updated, just rebase your local development on local master, and push to remote development. all should be good.

Comment: @SG, did everything workout well for you?

Comment: Yes working as expected.
Thanks for your prompt help